# address(this).balance not updating correctly

Tags: addresses, balances

I have made a few test contracts for this issue and I have come across the same result in all of them so it is obvious I am not understanding something.

In the following contract I keep track of the received ether in the `DepositedBalance` variable. I also check the value of `address(this).balance` via `NativeBalance`.

```js
    contract BalanceChecker{

        uint256 public DepositedBalance;
        uint256 public NativeBalance = address(this).balance;
        address public ContractAddress = address(this);
        
        receive() external payable {
            DepositedBalance += msg.value;
        }
 
    // 1. This function returns correct balance
    
        function ShowDepositedBalance() public view returns(uint256){
            return DepositedBalance;
        }
    
    // 2. This function always returns zero as balance:
    
        function ShowNativeBalance() public view returns(uint256){
            return NativeBalance;
        }
    
    // 3. This function returns correct balance when called with the contract address as argument
    
        function BalanceCheck(address _addr) public view returns(uint256){
            return address(_addr).balance;
        }
    
    }
```

The question is that **address(this).balance does never reflect any change** when I send ether to the contract, it is **always zero**. I created the variable `ContractAddress` only to confirm that the address matches that of the deployed contract, which it does.

Most surprisingly, when I externally call `BalanceCheck()` with the contract address (`ContractAddress`) as an argument **it does return the correct value** (¿?). This openly contradicts that `ContractAddress = address(this)`.

What am I missing here? what is wrong with `address(this)`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uint256 public NativeBalance = address(this).balance;
```

This line of code just initialized `NativeBalance` variable while deploying the contract (same effect as you assign initial value in the costructor fucntion) and will never be updated (you didn't update anywhere), it doesn't mean `NativeBalance` will track value of `address(this).balance;` automatically .

If you want the balance, address(this).balance is your best option, as some minor cases your contract's balance will be updated without executing any of your contract's code.

Comment: any suggestions whether the address(this).balance function in this question will reflect the changes immediately after transfer() function initiated, or only after it succeeds? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/152036/120999